# docker can't pull specific images with storage.googleapis.com error

Tags: docker, pull

I've been going around in circles on this one... so i've installed docker-ce 19.03.10-3 on centos7. i've noticed that when i try pulling say:

```
# docker pull "k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.17.6"
v1.17.6: Pulling from kube-proxy
83b4483280e5: Pulling fs layer
cedd2715c2e4: Pulling fs layer
297e97c9c472: Pulling fs layer
67b649411e75: Waiting
d97928a1765f: Waiting
ffa39a529ef3: Waiting
50782a16cc91: Waiting
error pulling image configuration: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/us.artifacts.google-containers.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:92f9a31ce92aa43379ef189ae7c6cfb2aadbf779fb3d979856bb7e5ee39f66c4: EOF
```

aha! it must be a networking problem (even though its on a public ip address), so i do

```
# cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://<squid-proxy>:3128
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=http://<squid-proxy>:3128
EOF
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart docker
```

but... same error again.

to make things more annoying, i tried it on a different node, on the same subnet and it succeeds! i thought it was initially because this host was on a different docker version (1.13); but i upgraded it to 19 and... it worked. made sure that `daemon.json` config on both machines were identical.

repos from dockerhub work fine, eg `docker pull centos:7` succeeds.

any other suggestions?